# Watch folder in transmission -- why do I have to acknowledge to add the torrent?

Tags: automation, bittorrent, dropbox, transmission

I use transmission on an ubuntu 10.10 nettop running the dropbox client. With transmission I watch a dropbox folder to which I add torrents on another computer. The syncing works great, and transmission pretty quickly finds the new file.

But transmission doesn't begin download. Instead, I have to acknowledge the new torrent by clicking `add`. Then download begins and everything is great.

Can I download without clicking `add`? It seems that I have every "automatic" option selected. Is there some setting file I need to alter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck `Show Options` checkbox & It will autostart without prompting you.

[image]